# Requesting two datetimes out of a table, but only getting one

Tags: java, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to get two datetime values out of a database, but I'm only get one of them at a time. By that I mean that if I remove the column I do get (begintijd) from the query I do get the other column (eindtijd).

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db", "username", "password");
resultTable = new ArrayList<>();
Statement statement = con.createStatement();
statement.execute(query)
ResultSet result = statement.getResultSet();
ResultSetMetaData resultData = result.getMetaData();
while (result.next()) {
  Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>();
  for (int i = 1; i <= resultData.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    String type = resultData.getColumnTypeName(i);
    switch (type) {
      case "INT":
        row.put(resultData.getColumnName(i), result.getInt(i));
        break;
      case "VARCHAR":
      case "CHAR":
      case "TEXT":
        row.put(resultData.getColumnName(i), result.getString(i));
        break;
      case "DATETIME":
        row.put(resultData.getColumnName(i), new java.util.Date(result.getTimestamp(i).getTime()));
        break;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Data type not supported");
    }
    i++;
  }
  resultTable.add(row);
}
```

This is my main:

```
String query = "SELECT begintijd, eindtijd, lesID FROM calendar WHERE lesID = 1";
ArrayList<Map<String, Object>> resultTable = Database.executeStatement(query);
System.out.println(resultTable);
```

As a result I get this (no errors):

```
[{begintijd=Tue Apr 07 08:30:00 CEST 2020, lesID=1}]
```

Here's a screenshot of my database:

[image: Image of my database]

Is there something wrong with my implementation of java.util.Date, or what?

Comment: It seems that you are incrementing `i` twice per iteration (see the `i++` at the end of the loop)  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm dumb.
I used an incremental for loop, and then incremented the index again at the end of each cycle, essentially skipping the even columns.